# How to modify registry value using command prompt?(reg_binary type)

Tags: command-line, windows-registry

I want to create a automatic registry update program using command prompt.
I tried several steps, most methods were to update Boolean values. But i want to update a REG_BINARY value.

Help needed !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're writing a batch script, the usual method is to import a prepared `.reg` file:

```
reg import myupdates.reg
```

You can create the files [by hand](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310516), or just by exporting the correct values via Regedit and deleting unnecessary parts (with a text editor).